# how to get chosen option value on hover/mouseover event using jquery chosen plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get option value on hover/mouseover event when option is hovered using chosen plugin....

Fiddle : [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/1/)

Here is js code...

```
   $("#myselect").chosen();

   $('#myselect').next('.chosen-container').on('mouseenter', 'li.active-result', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());
    alert($(this).val()); // how to get option value...?
   });
```

Comment: you can't get the option value while its not yet selected.

Comment: ooh is it ? any other way to get option value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USe delegate for that, because chosen plugin creates the `.active-result` class elements dynamically.

```
$("#myselect").chosen();

$(document).on("hover",".active-result",function(){
 alert($(this).text());   
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/2/)

**Edit**

```
$(document).on("hover",".active-result",function(){
    alert($("#myselect option").eq($(this).data("option-array-index")).val());

});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for binding the events to dynamically added DOM:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$("body").on('mouseenter','li.active-result',function(){
  alert($(this).data('option-array-index'));   
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6A6V/)**

Answer (score 1):

As this plugin created new elements for options and to read option value you need find option matching text and read its value:

```
$('#myselect').next('.chosen-container').on('mouseenter', 'li.active-result', function(e) {
    var currentText = $(this).text();
    alert($(this).text());
    alert($('#myselect option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == currentText; }).val()); // how to get option value...?
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4wCQh/14/)**

Comment: this will just display the array index. not it's value.

Comment: @ejay_francisco, yes you are right. I think then we need to make work around as this plugin does not save option value anywhere. Let me check